# Extreme negative number when calling car class

Tags: c++, class, negative-number

I nearly have this program finished but I keep getting an extreme negative number, and can not figure out why. It subtracts and adds 5 for each call of accelerate and decelerate like it should but the initial value of speed is far too low.

//header file

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

class Car
{
private:
    int yearModel;
    std::string make;
    int speed;
public:
    Car(int, std::string);
    int getYearModel() const
    { return yearModel; }
    std::string getMake() const
    { return make; }
    int getSpeed() const
    { return speed; }
    void accelerate();
    void brake();
};

#endif
```

//Implementation cpp file

```
 #include "Car.h"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    Car::Car(int y, string m)
    {
        yearModel = y;
        make = m;
    }

    void Car::accelerate()
    {
        speed += 5;
    }

    void Car::brake()
    {
        speed -= 5;
    }
```

//main program file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int yearModel, speed;
    string make;

    cout << "Enter the year and make of this car." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Year of Model (between 1980 and 2014):";
    cin >> yearModel;
    while ((yearModel < 1980) || (yearModel > 2014))
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry, enter a number between 1980 and 2014:";
        cin >> yearModel;
    }
    cout << "Make:";
    cin >> make;

    Car charger(yearModel, make);

    cout << "Car is at rest, currently traveling at " << charger.getSpeed() << " miles per hour, pressing accelerator." << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        charger.accelerate();
        cout << "Current speed is " << charger.getSpeed() << " miles per hour" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    cout << "Now pressing brake" << endl;



for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            charger.brake();
            cout << "Current speed is " << charger.getSpeed() << " miles per hour" << endl;
            system("pause");
        }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `speed` is never initialized or assigned anything, it's undefined behaviour to use it.

Answer (score 6):

You are not initializing `speed` in the constructor, it will not be zero initialized, it will be initialized with a indeterminate value from the memory block that the `Car` object is constructed in. Just initialize it to zero in the constructor and you should be fine:

```
Car::Car(int y, string m) : yearModel(y), make(m), speed(0) {}
                                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

`speed` is being [default initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) which means it will have an *indeterminate value* and using it without initialization would be [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: *Arbitrary* would be more accurate than *random*; the latter has a specific statistical meaning.

Comment: @KeithThompson hmm, yeah good point, another user edited it when I was in the middle of making some changes. I originally used indeterminate value.

Comment: *Indeterminate* is probably even better than *arbitrary*.